How to add provisioning profile to IPA file?
I downloaded an IPA off the web and I want to upload it to WORKSPACE ONE UEM by vmware for demo testing, but I keep getting errors I need to attach provisioning profile
How can I edit the IPA so I can successfully upload them to the demo sites?
how do I get a provisioning profile according to the existing IPA FILE
THANKS
need to attach theprovisioning profile file without it you cannot upload the IPA to the device
